Scan that splits accumulator and yielded value
Edit: the function I was asking for was mapAccumL
Problem: split a list of ints such that the sums of the sublists are bounded (by 10)
Here's how I would solve it in python using a scan to do the conditional logic:
l = random.choices(range(5), k=30)
[2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2]

scan_result = *itertools.accumulate(l, lambda acc, x: x if acc + x >= 10 else acc + x),
(2, 5, 8, 9, 4, 4, 7, 9, 9, 3, 6, 7, 9, 9, 2, 3, 5, 9, 4, 7, 8, 4, 6, 6, 9, 1, 5, 6, 6, 8)

adjacent_map = lambda fn, l: itertools.starmap(fn, zip(l, l[1:]))
mask = (0, *adjacent_map(lambda a, b: int(a > b), scan_result))
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

With the mask you can then cut you original list into the desired list of lists:
[[2,3,3,1],[4,0,3,2,0],[3,3,1,2,0],[2,1,2,4],[4,3,1],[4,2,0,3],[1,4,1,0,2]]

You could do it in one go in the scan by returning the mask as well. But then you lambda becomes awkward lambda acc, x: (x, 1, x) if acc[0] + x >= 10 else (acc[0] + x, 0, x).
This is not very satisfactory. It has poor separation of concerns. acc[0] is only needed for the logic of the scan and is not needed after. Only acc[1:] is needed after. What I want is a scan algorithm that splits what you return: result[0] becomes the next accumulator, result[1:] the yielded output of the scan.
Has this problem been solved before? Is there any prior art? Do people do this in haskell? Are there functions/operators in j or apl that do this?

Aside: It seems you have to write your own library to get half decent solutions. I think my problem is I program in c++ but don't write my own iterators/ranges.

This looks like Python? Why is this tagged Haskell, j, and apl?

what does "but don't write my own iterators/ranges." means?

I'm asking to an ideomatic haskell, solution. Python easy to write and read. If I wrote a Haskell solution it would be isomorphic to the python

OK, but why [tag:j] and [tag:apl] then? And why do you say you program in [tag:c++]?

I though you might have an algorithm for this???

Then state so in the question. Currently it just looks like you used the wrong tags.

Also, why link to a Jello cut?

@Adám it's a categorization of all the different flavours of these algorithms. Most languages don't support any of them. apl and j might do a few

I think one idiomatic way to do this in Haskell without explicit recursion is to use its laziness: we'll make the full list of sums, but only look deep enough in it to see something bigger than 10. Like this:
makeBins :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
makeBins n = unfoldr \case
    [] -> Nothing
    ns -> Just (splitAt (length (takeWhile (<n) (scanl1 (+) ns))) ns)

As a bonus, this handles lists with negative numbers more gracefully than your Python solution; however, it is slightly less lazy/GC-friendly than the explicit recursion solution in the other answer. This could be fixed, if that level of optimization is needed, by a function which probably ought to be in the libraries somewhere that combines splitAt and length:
splitAtLength :: [a] -> [b] -> ([b], [b])
splitAtLength (_:as) (b:bs) = let ~(l, r) = splitAtLength as bs in (b:l, r)
splitAtLength [] bs = ([], bs)

With splitAtLength in hand, the second clause of makeBins would become
ns -> Just (splitAtLength (takeWhile (<n) (scanl1 (+) ns)) ns)

and you'd have full laziness/GC-friendliness.

We can write our own solution with:
makeBins :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
makeBins t0 = go t0
    where go t xa@(x:xs)
            | x > t = [] : go t0 xa
            | otherwise = let ~(y:ys) = go (t-x) xs in (x:y) : ys
          go _ [] = [[]]

this then gives us for the sample data:
ghci> makeBins 10 [2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2]
[[2,3,3,1],[4,0,3,2,0],[3,3,1,2,0],[2,1,2,4],[4,3,1],[4,2,0,3,1],[4,1,0,2]]

which thus makes bins with 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 10, and 7 as subtotals.

It seems from OP's example that the desired result has sums 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, and 8.

No that looks like the right answer. Cutting the list such that the sums dont exceed a bound. It's a really common problem

So you're saying it's idiomatic in Haskell to use recursion for this. If they did this with iteration, would they just do it the ugly way??

What gave you the impression that iteration exists in Haskell?  Anything in Haskell that even looks like iteration is actually recursion.

@LouisWasserman sorry by iteration I meant encapsulating the recursion in fold and scan

https://haskell.godbolt.org/z/ExoKqh3xG
With mapAccumL and  the starling combinator 1 2 which is <*>/ap for the reader monad in Haskell.
splitByMask :: [Bool] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]

fn :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Bool)
fn = \acc x -> if acc + x >= 10 then (x, True) else (acc + x, False)

makeBins :: (a -> Int -> (a, Bool)) -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
makeBins fn = ((flip splitByMask) <*> (snd . mapAccumL fn 0))


See here for programming with combinators in Haskell https://youtu.be/umb5vTP_g7c?t=1518

Your split_scanl is almost mapAccumL.  It's the same except that mapAccumL returns the final state as well as the list.

What's splitByMask?

@DavidFletcher Thanks, this was what I was asking for

@DanielWagner paste link. ChatGPT wrote it. It was in the Godbolt link

@TomHuntington Answers should be self-contained. Linking to additional info is fine, but linking to the answer itself is not. Also beware: gpt-written answers are not permitted.
